# 500 status error on python web crawler for cubetutor (magic the gathering site)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler, session-cookies

This is my code that was working:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
cookies = {
    'JSESSIONID': '15EA1C17E103E8206BAFFF73FA157231',
}

headers = {
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'http://www.cubetutor.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'http://www.cubetutor.com/topcardsbyset/1;jsessionid=15EA1C17E103E8206BAFFF73FA157231',
}

data = {
  't:ac': '1',
  't:formdata': 'byjWim5rtLJcD8P4BWZe94Mn6II=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWOPQ4BQRSAH4lCdBIRPe1oaKiQqEQkywHezj5rZOxM5j1/l3ECcQmFzh0cQKtS2DiARPsV3/edn1DaN6A+d36EIeHhMSLpMQmTJS0coOtCqtCjXpES9MQSjl2lXSBrYhUjkxrEOUQtY0M2aeaCrW8trpVH7fYuQmECFe0yCc5OcUMC1ckad9i2mKXtSILJ0v7BC5TzaPSN/v4Z/PszC04Tc7SNN4bZuOx6STrL1+leBDj4DxyMK0MBAQAA',
  'setSelect': '10E',
  't:zoneid': 'topCardsZone'
}

response = bs4(requests.post('http://www.cubetutor.com/topcardsbyset.topcardsform', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data).json()['content'], 'lxml')
text = response.text.split("\n")
file = text.pop(0)
link = response.find_all("a")
arr = {file : {}}
for i in range(len(link)):
    arr[file][text[i]] = link[i]

print(file)
for i in arr[file]:
    print(i," : ", arr[file][i])
```

All the stuff from text = response.text.split("\n") on is not important (not finished and not where the issue is). This code up top is all working fine but it requires me to go to the site and look in the network requests/headers and get all this info every time. I am trying to automate the process a bit but the second i try to create my own jsession id so that i didnt have to keep going to the site it gives me a 500 status error. At first i thought it might be because the jsession id and the headers didnt match so i changed it to also equal session.headers as you can see below but that didnt fix anything. The code is at https://github.com/icarus612/spiderPY-magicTG/ if you want to look at the other commits. Any help would be great.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

data = {
  't:ac': '1',
  't:formdata': 'byjWim5rtLJcD8P4BWZe94Mn6II=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWOPQ4BQRSAH4lCdBIRPe1oaKiQqEQkywHezj5rZOxM5j1/l3ECcQmFzh0cQKtS2DiARPsV3/edn1DaN6A+d36EIeHhMSLpMQmTJS0coOtCqtCjXpES9MQSjl2lXSBrYhUjkxrEOUQtY0M2aeaCrW8trpVH7fYuQmECFe0yCc5OcUMC1ckad9i2mKXtSILJ0v7BC5TzaPSN/v4Z/PszC04Tc7SNN4bZuOx6STrL1+leBDj4DxyMK0MBAQAA',
  'setSelect': '10E',
  't:zoneid': 'topCardsZone'
}

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get('http://www.cubetutor.com')
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()
headers = session.headers
headers['Referer'] =  f"http://www.cubetutor.com/topcardsbyset/1;jsessionid={cookies['JSESSIONID']}"
headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
headers['Origin'] = 'http://www.cubetutor.com'
headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

print(r)
response = session.get('http://www.cubetutor.com/topcardsbyset.topcardsform', headers=headers, data=data, cookies=cookies)
print(response)
#text = response.find_all(class_='compareCubeColumn').text
#link = response.find_all("a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work (didn't include the `bs4` parsing):

```
import requests

def get_session_cookie():
    resp = requests.get("https://www.cubetutor.com")
    if resp.ok and resp.cookies:
        return resp.cookies.get_dict()


def post_query():
    session_cookie = get_session_cookie()
    headers = {
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Origin': 'https://www.cubetutor.com',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'https://www.cubetutor.com/topcardsbyset/1;jsessionid=15EA1C17E103E8206BAFFF73FA157231',
    }
    data = {
      't:ac': '1',
      't:formdata': 'byjWim5rtLJcD8P4BWZe94Mn6II=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWOPQ4BQRSAH4lCdBIRPe1oaKiQqEQkywHezj5rZOxM5j1/l3ECcQmFzh0cQKtS2DiARPsV3/edn1DaN6A+d36EIeHhMSLpMQmTJS0coOtCqtCjXpES9MQSjl2lXSBrYhUjkxrEOUQtY0M2aeaCrW8trpVH7fYuQmECFe0yCc5OcUMC1ckad9i2mKXtSILJ0v7BC5TzaPSN/v4Z/PszC04Tc7SNN4bZuOx6STrL1+leBDj4DxyMK0MBAQAA',
      'setSelect': '10E',
      't:zoneid': 'topCardsZone'
    }
    return requests.post('https://www.cubetutor.com/topcardsbyset.topcardsform', headers=headers, cookies=session_cookie, data=data).json()

# resp = post_query()
# print(resp)
# {u'content': u"<div class='centeredContainer'><div class='compa ...
```

Comment: ok thanks! I'll give this a try. It seems like you basically just didnt use a new ```requests.Session()```. Did you not have to save the jsession id and use it in your Referer for headers?

Comment: @ellishogan, Yup, I avoided explicitly instantiating a `requests.Session` object and simply passed the cookies from the first request to the second - along with the hard-coded headers I got from your question. Also, I switched to HTTPS for good measure and just in case the site uses secure cookies. The referer didn't seem to matter.

Comment: This works! i took it out of the functions for myself but it works either way (with one small exception ( your data object was wrong at  't:formdata' it looks like something got cut off) but as soon as i changed that to the one i had it worked perfectly. thanks.

Comment: @ellishogan, Ah yes, good catch. That's a copy/paste mistake on my part. I'll update the answer for posterity.